# Is there an approximate counting equation for paths in a directed acyclic graph with known average out degree and number of vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

If I have a directed acyclic graph (DAG) where I know the average out degree and the exact number of vertices, is there a counting equation to give me the expected number of paths?

---

**Edit**

Thanks for the feedback in the comments. I've added the following that I hope clarify my question.

- I'm looking for the total number of unique paths among all pairs of vertices.
- The average out degree over all vertices in the DAG is known, but the average out degree of any specific vertex is not known.

---

Comment: The number of paths between 2 fixed vertices? The number of paths total? By "expected" do you mean each vertex has an expected out degree which is known?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor, thanks for your feedback. I've added that information into my question.